# If I roll a 6 sided die infinite times, each time calculating the sum of all rolls. What is the probability the sum will be 2023 after a certain roll.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, summation, dice

So after each time you roll the dice you find the sum of the current roll and the previous rolls. As this number get larger by 1 to 6 each time will it will pass 2023 at some point. What is the probability it will land exactly on 2023 after a roll?

I feel like I can solve this with some kind of a recursion or a matrix solution using a Markov Chain. However I am not sure how exactly to do this.

Comment: My guess is approximately $2~/7.~$  Since the average roll is $~3.5,~$ I would expect $~2~$ out of every $~7~$ numbers to get hit.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to solve the linear system of equations
\begin{align*}
p_n &= \tfrac16(p_{n+1}+p_{n+2}+p_{n+3}+p_{n+4}+p_{n+5}+p_{n+6}) \quad (0\le n\le 2022) \\
p_{2023} &= 1 \\
p_n &= 0 \quad (n\ge 2024).
\end{align*}
Do you see why this gives $p_0$ as the desired probability?

Comment: Isn't that just a re-statement of the question?

Comment: I see why $p_0$ would be the probability. However I don't fully understand why $p_{2023}$ is 1 and how to solve the system. Is $p_{2023}=1$ because we want to force $p_{2023}$ to occur? Or is there another reason? In terms of solving this system do I use a Matrix of some kind? I can see one of them being a column vector looking like $\begin{bmatrix} p_{n+1} \\ p_{n+2} \\ \vdots \\ p_{n+6} \end{bmatrix}$. However I don't really have any ideas beyond that.

Comment: $p_n$ is the probability that, if we start at the number $n$, then $2023$ will be hit at some point; that's why $p_{2023}=1$. You can solve the system however you would normally solve a system of linear equations (presumably with a computer's help).

Comment: @Beyond555 What Greg Martin's response is indicating is that you have to do the following in order to get an **exact answer**.  First, for any value of $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 7}},~$ and for any value of $~k~$ in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\},~$ let $~p_k~$ denote the probability of landing on $~n,~$ assuming that you have landed on $~(n - k).~$ Note that $~p_k~$ is **independent** of $~n.~$ ...see next comment

Comment: @Beyond555 Then, working backwords, you have to **similarly** compute the probability of landing on $~2022~$ as a function of the probability of landing on each of $~2021, \cdots, 2016.~$ Then, you have to compute the probability of landing on $~2021~$ as a function of the probability of landing on each of $~2020, \cdots, 2015.~$  So, you work backwards, with a computer program, perhaps using floating point arithmetic.  This implies that you will be satisfied with an answer exact to (for example) perhaps 10-20 decimal points.  ...see next comment

Comment: @Beyond555 As I indicated in my initial comment, immediately following the posted question, I suspect that the answer will approach $~2/7.$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork No, it isn't just a restatement.  See my comments following this answer.  What Greg Martin's answer provides (with my explanatory comments) is a procedure that (theoretically) could be followed with pencil and paper to get an exact answer.  So, writing a computer program to do the leg work, and being satisfied with *floating point accuracy* seems reasonable.  Note that this is probably the exact procedure used to attack BlackJack, in the 1960's.

Comment: @Beyond555 Assuming that you accept the strategy of writing your own computer program, and depending on your programming skills, one moderate simplification is to first (in effect) compute $~p_1, p_2, \cdots, p_6,~$ which represent landing on $~n,~$ if you start from each of $~(n-1), \cdots, (n-6),~$ respectively.  Then, you could use these results to **programmatically** compute $~p_7, p_8, \cdots, p_{12}.~$  Then, you could use these results to **programmatically** compute $~p_{13}, p_{14}, \cdots, p_{24},~$ and so forth.